# Why does feta taste so terribly salty when grilled?

Tags: cheese, feta

I love feta cheese, and I can't get enough of it, just like my family. But unlike them, I only eat it raw. I can't stand the grilled feta sandwiches my mother eats every morning for breakfast, and the reason is that, when the feta is grilled, it turns terribly salty and sharp.

The reason can't be just melting, because I enjoy lots of dishes which are baked with feta in the filling, as long as it doesn't get any direct heat.

What is the reason for this taste change? Can it be prevented?

Comment: I don't share this experience ... the feta our grocer stocks gets creamy, and if anything less salty-tasting, when heated.  Maybe you should try a different brand?

Answer (score 10):

Just speculation: Since feta is a brined cheese (and can have up to 56% moisture content), and is already inherent salty, when melted and in direct heat, a lot of the water content evaporates, essentially concentrating the taste.

Comment: I think this is exactly right. Saltiness is a matter of the concentration of salt in the finished product. Less water for the same salt means it gets saltier.